# statistical test for count

Tags: descriptive-statistics, count-data

I have two groups of the same number of subjects. 
For each subject I counted the total number of pauses in a reading task. To test if there is a difference between the two groups with respect to this count what kind of statistical test is correct to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test.

A slightly fancier approach would be a regression model appropriate for count data.  This might be Poisson regression, or a more flexible variety like negative binomial regression.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sal... If instead I transform the data in percentage, what are the most appropriate statistical tests?

Comment: I think you would have to describe how you are getting the percentage.

Comment: Well..In this second case I have the count of unique words pronounced in a speaking task. I read the Poisson regression "only be performed when the mean count is a small value (e.g., less than 10)". But I can transform the count in percentage (unique words/ total words *100) or in proportion. What kind of statistics can I perform in this second case?

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that about Poisson regression.  In the case of proportions, you could use the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney.  Or a fancier approach would be beta regression.